# What does pointer_traits provide for types that are neither X<A, T...> nor provide a member typedef element_type?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

What is the result of following? Is it illformed, undefined behavior or welldefined and wellformed?

```
struct A {};
std::pointer_traits<A> x;
```

The reason I ask is because I want to know for curiousity, and because I want to know whether an arbitrary type is a pointer. With that I also mean to include shared_ptr and friends. I wondered whether there is a type trait (predicate) for that or, if not, whether I can use pointer_traits and detect whether element_type is declared or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says it is ill-formed as from 20.6.3p1 since it doesn't have `element_type` and is not a class template instantiation

> typedef see below element_type;
>
> Type: Ptr::element_type if such a
>   type exists; otherwise, T if Ptr is a class template instantiation of
>   the form `SomePointer<T, Args>`, where Args is zero or more type
>   arguments; **otherwise, the specialization is ill-formed**.

Comment: thanks. do you know what is the best way to query whether some type is "pointer like"?

Comment: @Johannes: Define "pointer like". You can likely create some kind of concept through expression SFINAE.

Comment: Checking for existence of `element_type` would get the standard "pointer-like types", but since anything with the form `SomePointer<T, Args>` is also acceptable, I'm not sure (also the standard doesn't seem to clarify what "pointer-like types" means AFAICT).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Is the inquiry in reference to not only the trival (something that answers true to `std::is_pointer<>`) but potentially also overrides or inherits `operator->()` and `operator *()` ? The question seems very interesting.

Comment: i see. i will probably provide explicit partial specializations, as it seems to me to be impossible to prevent matching iterators or other silly nonpointer types.